# Bootstrap 4 card layout width not consistent

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

My page has three cards in it as shown in image 1. The cards are not the same width in columns 1. When testing it on the mobile (Chrome) they are all different widths and the bottom two cards are touching as shown in image 2.

How do I get the columns on the left to be the same width and maintain responsiveness and size when on mobile? I'm expecting uniform width and height on both web and mobile.

My code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card rounded-0">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">Numbers</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body" style="font-size: small; overflow-y: scroll;">                       
                        My Content                        
                    </div>
                </div>               
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card rounded-0">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h6 class="mb-0">More Numbers</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="font-size: small;">
                            My Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="card rounded-0">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Some stuff</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" style="font-size: small;">
                My Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Layout on web page:[image: Layout on web page]

The layout on mobile:[image: Layout on mobile]

https://www.codeply.com/go/Fia8Y6YPNl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking the bootstrap rule of always having div.col-* being a child of a div.row. A div.col-* cannot be a direct child of another div.col-*. This is likely your issue.

Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card rounded-0">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h6 class="mb-0">Numbers</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="font-size: small; overflow-y: scroll;">
                            My Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card rounded-0">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h6 class="mb-0">Numbers</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="font-size: small; overflow-y: scroll;">
                            My Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card rounded-0">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Numbers</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="font-size: small; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    My Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code I edited was from a previous question on here. Are you saying you cannot have columns under a row in the syntax...I'm afraid Bootstrap is not my thing.

Comment: Ok... I worked out what you meant and fixed it...I now have another problem.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin added code example

Comment: While that worked and the width problem is fixed, the problem I now have is the two on the left are touching and the large card on the right is not the same height as the column that the two cards are in. I suppose my next question is how do I get the item on the right to be the same height as the column on the left...

Comment: I just saw your update...I'll try that...

Comment: Yep same problem, that works great but a problem with the height as mentione in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm tired and didn't notice the thing I had on the right card was massive. I shrunk it and now it works perfectly, thank you loads...

Comment: Glad to help! Yeah fatigue is the worst, remember to take breaks! Have a good night.